# Syncfusion GridList Control Column Header Click

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I would like to order contents in a column when user clicks column header on the Syncfusion GridList control. Does anyone have any idea on how I might achieve this using C#?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have them installed right now but it should be something like this:

```
GridControl.TableDescriptor.AllowSort = true;
```

This should make the columns sortable, thus when clicking on the column header it will order them.